# Dynamic content doesn't work when loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load some dynamic content after the user has logged in, using `$.ajax`, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "functions.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: login_info,
    datatype: 'html',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#main').html(response);
    }
});
```

The problem is, that some events don't work, when loaded this way. I fixed the buttons with the `.live()` method, but a sortable list for example, doesn't work. How can I somehow refresh the DOM, and let jquery know of these new added elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to reinitialize UI components in `$.ajax`'s success callback, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "functions.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: login_info,
    datatype: 'html',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#main').html(response);
        $("#main .sortable").sortable();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple answer. I have just been coding a jQuery script and faced the same problem.

Just use [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F), i.e. the "Rebinding" solution